# Inserting in database using java1001

Tags: java, sql, methods

I always get this error every time i try to save or execute the query.
I can't work it out,maybe alittle advice will help.

> java.sql.SQLException: can not issue data manipulation statements with
>   executeQuery()

here is my code for inserting into my database.

```
Connection conn=null; ResultSet rs = null,rs1=null; PreparedStatement
pst = null,pst1=null;

DefaultTableModel model= (DefaultTableModel)tbl_stud.getModel();



    try{
       String sql="INSERT INTO students (id_num,fname,mname,lname,course,gender,year,username,password) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"; 
        model.setNumRows(0);
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);   
         String id=txt_idnum.getText();
        pst.setString(1,id);
        String f=txt_fname.getText();
        pst.setString(2, f);
        String m=txt_mname.getText();
        pst.setString(3, m);
        String l=txt_lname.getText();
        pst.setString(4, l);
        String crs=cmb_course.getSelectedItem().toString();
        pst.setString(5, crs);
         String gen=cmb_gender.getSelectedItem().toString();
        pst.setString(6, gen);
         String year = cmb_year.getSelectedItem().toString();
        pst.setString(7, year);
        String uname=txt_username.getText();
        pst.setString(8, uname);
        String pass=txt_password.getText();
        pst.setString(9, pass);

        pst.executeQuery(sql);


    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved!","",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);


    }
    catch(Exception e){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e,"",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use pst.executeUpdate rather then pst.executeQuery

Comment: thank you. but i got this error after i changed it 
"You have an error in your SQL Syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server versiom for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?'

Comment: try leaving out the semi-colon

Comment: String sql="INSERT INTO students (id_num,fname,mname,lname,course,gender,year,username,password) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

alreaady try that code

Comment: Not sure then. Can any of the values be null? You might need to use the setNull type in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The exception message says it all:

> can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()

Instead, you should use `executeUpdate()`. Additionally, if you've already prepared the statement, you should use the execute variants that do not receive a String argument. Those are inherited from `Statement` and should not be used with `PreparedStatement`s (and yes, this does go a long way towards showing that JDBC is a terrible API).

```
pst.executeUpdate();
```

As an additional sidenote, you should drop the semicolon (`;`) and the end of your insert statement. Depending on the exact driver and RDBMS you're using it may either be redundant or just plain out wrong.